# Dynamically creating the volume based on the size of ubifs image size

Tags: ubifs

I have a requirement to create a new volume (it can be static) based on the size of the ubifs image (say rootfs.ubifs) which I am going to write into that volume. The aim is to create the volume with the minimum possible size required to write 'rootfs.ubifs' to that volume and boot the device from it.

Can somebody please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the [overhead of the **UBI** layer](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubi.html#L_overhead).  This is documented as `O` in the web page or,

- `O` - the overhead related to storing EC and VID headers in bytes, i.e. O = SP - SL.

`SP` is a physical erase block size and `SL` is what **UbiFs** will get.  Usually, it is the minimum *page* size times two.  One for an `EC` and another for a `VID`; these are the two structures that **UBI** uses to manage the flash.  Both are defined in [*ubi-media.h*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/mtd/ubi/ubi-media.h).  `EC` is the `ubi_ec_hdr` structure and `VID` is the `ubi_vid_hdr` structure.  The `EC` or *erase count* is written every time an erase block is erased and this is responsible for *wear leveling*.<sup>*note*</sup>  The `VID` or *volume id* header allows **UBI** to support multiple volumes and provide the *PEB* to *LEB* (physical to logical erase block) management.

So for a 2k page **NAND** flash without sub-pages, it is 4k; if sub-pages are supported then it is possible to put both headers in the same page and only 2k is needed.  If your flash page size differs, you just need to multiply by two without sub-pages and only add the page overhead if you have sub-pages.  The overhead for **NOR** flash is 256 bytes as it doesn't have the idea of *pages*.

In order to create your *rootfs.ubifs*, you must have specified a *logic erase block* size (to `mkfs.ubifs`).  The difference between *logical erase block* (`LEB`) and *physical erase block* (`PEB`) is just the overhead documented above.  Multiply your *rootfs.ubifs* by `PEB`/`LEB` to get the minimum possible size for the *UBI volume*.

*note:* If an erase is interrupted (reset/power cycle) between the actual erase and the `EC` write, an average of all other *erase blocks* is used to set the erase count when **UBI** re-reads the *ubi device*.